# failed to stop media muxer

Tags: android, mediamuxer

And here's the code that I have used for mixing a Video with an audio.The output is file is create but there is no data in that and while the running the application I am getting above error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.mediamux, PID: 5651
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mediamux/com.example.mediamux.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to stop the muxer
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
            at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1957)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7099)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
         Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to stop the muxer
            at android.media.MediaMuxer.nativeStop(Native Method)
            at android.media.MediaMuxer.stop(MediaMuxer.java:454)
            at com.example.mediamux.MainActivity.muxing(MainActivity.java:133)
            at com.example.mediamux.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7327)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7318)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1275)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3103)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266) 
            at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1957) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7099) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965) 
    W/System: A resource failed to call release. 
    D/MPEG4Writer: Video track stopping. Stop source
        Audio track stopping. Stop source
```

Here's the error that I am getting while running the application on my phone.please help me I am very new in media muxer,media codec and media extractor library.

```
package com.example.mediamux;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.media.MediaCodec;
import android.media.MediaExtractor;
import android.media.MediaFormat;
import android.media.MediaMuxer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION = 200;
    private boolean permissionToRecordAccepted = false;
    private String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
    MediaMuxer muxer;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION);
        muxing();

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION:
                permissionToRecordAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                break;
        }
        if (!permissionToRecordAccepted) finish();

    }

    public void muxing() {

        String outputFile = "";

        try {

            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageState() + "/final2.mp4");
            file.createNewFile();
            outputFile = file.getAbsolutePath();
            MediaExtractor videoExtractor = new MediaExtractor();
            videoExtractor.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/vd1.avi");
            MediaExtractor audioExtractor = new MediaExtractor();
            audioExtractor.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/audio.aac");
            muxer = new MediaMuxer(outputFile, MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);
            videoExtractor.selectTrack(0);
            MediaFormat videoFormat = videoExtractor.getTrackFormat(0);
            int videoTrack = muxer.addTrack(videoFormat);

            audioExtractor.selectTrack(0);
            MediaFormat audioFormat = audioExtractor.getTrackFormat(0);
            int audioTrack = muxer.addTrack(audioFormat);
            boolean sawEOS = false;
            int frameCount = 0;
            int offset = 100;
            int sampleSize = 256 * 1024;
            ByteBuffer videoBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(sampleSize);
            ByteBuffer audioBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(sampleSize);
            MediaCodec.BufferInfo videoBufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
            MediaCodec.BufferInfo audioBufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();


            videoExtractor.seekTo(0, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC);
            audioExtractor.seekTo(0, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC);

            muxer.start();

            while (!sawEOS) {
                videoBufferInfo.offset = offset;
                videoBufferInfo.size = videoExtractor.readSampleData(videoBuf, offset);


                if (videoBufferInfo.size < 0 || audioBufferInfo.size < 0) {
                    // Log.d(TAG, "saw input EOS.");
                    sawEOS = true;
                    videoBufferInfo.size = 0;

                } else {
                    videoBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = videoExtractor.getSampleTime();
                    videoBufferInfo.flags = videoExtractor.getSampleFlags();
                    muxer.writeSampleData(videoTrack, videoBuf, videoBufferInfo);
                    videoExtractor.advance();


                    frameCount++;

                }
            }

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "frame:" + frameCount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            boolean sawEOS2 = false;
            int frameCount2 = 0;
            while (!sawEOS2) {
                frameCount2++;

                audioBufferInfo.offset = offset;
                audioBufferInfo.size = audioExtractor.readSampleData(audioBuf, offset);

                if (videoBufferInfo.size < 0 || audioBufferInfo.size < 0) {
                    //  Log.d(TAG, "saw input EOS.");
                    sawEOS2 = true;
                    audioBufferInfo.size = 0;
                } else {
                    audioBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = audioExtractor.getSampleTime();
                    audioBufferInfo.flags = audioExtractor.getSampleFlags();
                    muxer.writeSampleData(audioTrack, audioBuf, audioBufferInfo);
                    audioExtractor.advance();

                }
            }

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "frame:" + frameCount2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                muxer.stop();
                muxer.release();




        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Errorc", " " + e);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I faced with the same problem few days ago and solve it by send null data with 0 size and set "BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM" flag after the last data item was sent

Comment: can u explain by writing code as answer I am very new in this.